# How to remove a project directory that "cargo new" created

Tags: linux, bash, directory, rust-cargo, rmdir

I, by mistake, have created a new project directory with `cargo new communicator --bin`, instead of `cargo new communicator --lib`.

Then, I tried to remove the entire directory with `rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty communicator`. This command doesn't generate an error in the next line, but when I look to see if it's removed it's still there!

I wonder why I cannot remove a project directory in this fashion.

I tried both on Atom's Terminal Window and MX Linux Xfce Terminal, but the same result... Also, just in case I performed the same `rmdir` command as a root, but in vain.

Am I fundamentally doing something wrong here?

Comment: Cargo does not do anything special when creating a directory. It’s just a regular Git (by default) repository with a `Cargo.toml` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cargo doesn't do anything "special" with the project folder. If you accidentally created a `--bin` project instead of a library, You can

1. Delete the communicator bin project with `rm -rf communicator` where r is for recursive and f is to force remove(in case folder is not empty).
2. Delete `communicator/src/main.rs` and create `communicator/src/lib.rs`.

The second option has the same effect as deleting the `--bin` project and creating a library.

Comment: You don't need `-f` and you should not use it! This is very error prone and can delete important files in a unfortunate circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

The flag `--ignore-fail-on-non-empty` doesn't mean that `rmdir` goes ahead and removes the directory. It simply silences the error. Instead, you can use `rm -r communicator`.